# Use of symbol | & &~ and ~ in capability.h file

Tags: c, linux-kernel, posix, embedded-linux

I was reading a file capability.h given [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/capability.h#L113)
I am not clear as how can symbols `|` `~` `&` and `&~` be used in function calls what are they doing in

Use of `|` in following function call:

```
static inline kernel_cap_t cap_combine(const kernel_cap_t a,
                                       const kernel_cap_t b)
{
        kernel_cap_t dest;
        CAP_BOP_ALL(dest, a, b, |);
        return dest;
}
```

Use of `&` in following system call:

```
static inline kernel_cap_t cap_intersect(const kernel_cap_t a,
                                         const kernel_cap_t b)
{
        kernel_cap_t dest;
        CAP_BOP_ALL(dest, a, b, &);
        return dest;
}
```

Use of `&~` in following function:

```
static inline kernel_cap_t cap_drop(const kernel_cap_t a,
                                    const kernel_cap_t drop)
{
        kernel_cap_t dest;
        CAP_BOP_ALL(dest, a, drop, &~);
        return dest;
}
```

Use of `~` in following function:

```
static inline kernel_cap_t cap_invert(const kernel_cap_t c)
{
        kernel_cap_t dest;
        CAP_UOP_ALL(dest, c, ~);
        return dest;
}
```

Comment: They're used in the context of a macro, so when that macro is expanded, the "passed-in" operator is just present in some expression.

Comment: ok I got you on it is defined as #define CAP_BOP_ALL(c, a, b, OP) but then what does OP means or how can it be used?

Comment: It depends on the definition of `CAP_BOP_ALL` - for example, it could expand to `c = a OP b`, with `OP` substituted with `|`, `&`, etc, to have different effects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example CAP_BOP_ALL is defined as

```
#define CAP_BOP_ALL(c, a, b, OP)                                    \
do {                                                                \
        unsigned __capi;                                            \
        CAP_FOR_EACH_U32(__capi) {                                  \
                c.cap[__capi] = a.cap[__capi] OP b.cap[__capi];     \
        }                                                           \
} while (0)
```

so the "expression"

```
CAP_BOP_ALL(dest, a, b, |);
```

expands to

```
do {
        unsigned __capi;
        for (__capi = 0; __capi < _KERNEL_CAPABILITY_U32S; ++__capi) {
                dest.cap[__capi] = a.cap[__capi] | b.cap[__capi];
        }
} while (0);
```

. Even though the original expression doesn't look like correct C, it is because the C parser only gets it when the preprocessor is done and made it look like the latter expression.

Comment: Hmm the example you gave is probably expanding  CAP_FOR_EACH_U32 are you sure if it is expanding CAP_BOP_ALL in case yes can you give me a link to some thing to read because I came across such kind of macros for the first time

Comment: Ok I got you yes they are macros getting expanded

Comment: Registered User: `CAP_FOR_EACH_U32(__capi)` is #defined as `for (__capi = 0; __capi < _KERNEL_CAPABILITY_U32S; ++__capi)` (line 51 of `capability.h`). BTW, CAP_BOP_ALL is #defined in line 97.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, these `CAP_` things aren't functions, but rather preprocessor macros. And you can pass any preprocessing tokens to macros.

Comment: so what does some thing like | ,& or &~ or ~ stands for in a preprocessor macro

Answer (score 2):

Those are almost certainly preprocessor macros, for which the arguments are raw tokens, not parsed as operators.

Comment: so what does some thing like | ,& or &~ or ~ stands for in a preprocessor macro can you give me some link that can explain me its use as given in question

Comment: Impossible to say for sure without looking at macro definitions. For example, you can `#define MY_MACRO(op) (1 op 2)` and use `MY_MACRO(+)` and `MY_MACRO(&~)`. Here it's just a piece of source code substituted into an expression. `CAP_` probably has something similar but more sensible.